# Swift NSUserDefaults TableView multiple cells

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

When we type something in the textField and when we press button it saves content of textField into Nsuserdefaults. In other View Controller TableView reads that NSUserDefaults and displays only one cell. And when we go back in first ViewController to type something else in the textField and we press button again we only get again one cell in tableVIew. How can tableView display multiple cells when we type something in textField?

**ViewController.swift**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {  
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

   @IBAction func add2(sender: UIButton) {
       var connection = self.textField.text
       defaults.setObject(connection, forKey: "text")
    }
}
```

**ViewController2.swift**

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var ourText = String()

    var textArray:[String] = [String]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self

        ourText = defaults.stringForKey("text")!
        textArray.append(ourText)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {    
        return textArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {        
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = textArray[indexPath.row]

        return cell    
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because you are storing one value and overriding it each time, you are supposed to use array and append the value each time your adding.

This should work fine for you, in your ViewController define array and then use it to store your data.

```
 array.append(connection)
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey: "text")
```

**Note:** in `ViewController` `viewWillAppear` equal the array to the `NSUserDefaults` so when you append it, it has the old value and then you add the new value to it in save function like :

```
array = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("text")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    var array:NSMutableArray = NSMutableArray();//create array if you are playing between the two view controllers

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func add2(sender: UIButton) {

    var connection = self.textField.text
    var dataDic:NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary();
    dataDic.setObject(self.textField.text, forKey: "your key");
    // add object in array
    array.addObject(dataDic);

    //push your array like

    var viewController2Obj = ViewController2(nibName: "ViewController2", bundle: nil);
    viewController2Obj.arrayText = array;
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController2Obj, animated: true);
    }

}
```

ViewController2

```
class ViewController2: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate,  UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var arrayText:NSMutableArray!;


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.tableView.delegate = self
    self.tableView.dataSource = self

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) ->  Int {

    return arrayText.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath:  NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

     let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
     let dataDic = arrayText[indexPath.row] as NSMutableDictionary
     cell.textLabel?.text = dataDic.valueforkey("your key") as String;
     return cell

}


}
```